# Data not updated on angular component sometime

Tags: javascript, angular, docker

Sometime data is not being updated on angular component.
[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dozXz.png)
when I reload the page the get updated data.
[Updated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsDhi.png)
This happens sometimes when I navigate from one page to another.

Earlier I am using window.location.href function which reloads the page every time I navigate from one page to another but I have to containerized this application in docker container. Through which I am not able to access the browser window object. So now I am using route.navigate function for navigation.

below is the code snippet for API Service

```
getAllUser(id:any):Observable<any>{
    let ids=id;
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiurl}/${ids}`);
  }


getuserinformation(id:any):Observable<any>{
    let ids = id;
    return this.http.get(`${this.users}/${ids}`)
 }

getDataFromTopology(teamname:any):Observable<any>{
  let teamName= teamname;
  console.log(teamName);
  return this.http.get(`${this.topology}/${teamName}`);
}

getCurrentStatus():Observable<any>{
    // let dateTime= time;
    return this.http.get(`${this.userdeviceinfo}`);
  }


getDistinctProjectsInfo(id:any):Observable<any>{
  let access= 'access';
  let ids= id;
  return this.http.get(`${this.project}/${ids}/${access}`);
 }
```

```
this.apiservice.getAllUser(this.getparamid).subscribe((res)=>
    {
      
      this.heading='yes';
      this.left='yes';
      this.readUser=res.data;
      console.log(res.data, "read user dta");


      console.log(this.readUser)
      
      
      
    });
   
    this.apiservice.getuserinformation(this.getparamid).subscribe((res)=>{
      this.teamname= res.data[0].teamname;
      console.log(this.teamname, 'teamname')
      this.apiservice.getDataFromTopology(this.teamname).subscribe((res)=>{
  
        this.topologyInformation= res.data;
        for(let i=0;i<this.topologyInformation.length;i++){
       
          this.devicesInTopology.push(parseInt(this.topologyInformation[i].deviceid));
        }

        console.log(this.topologyInformation, this.devicesInTopology);
        

      })
    })
    this.apiservice.getCurrentStatus().subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log(res.data, "current status data");
        this.currentStatus= res.data;
        for(let i=0;i<this.currentStatus.length;i++){
          this.currentStatusArr.push(this.currentStatus[i].deviceid);
        }
         console.log(this.currentStatus, "current status array");
    })
    this.apiservice.getDistinctProjects(this.getparamid).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.projects=res.data;
    })
```

Comment: Seems to me like you're subscribing to some api/backend, but trying to display the data before the sub returns a value. Can you share the code that sets/gets the data for page?

Comment: Could you paste into your question a snippet of the code you're using for getting the data? That could help us help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I  have added apiservice and component code for your help

Comment: Please look and provide some solution